# what is a vector perpendicular to a plane of vectors

Tags: machine-learning, python, linear-algebra

I have 3 or 4 vectors connected that forms a plane. How can I find the vector that is perpendicular to this plane?

it can be a unit vector as long as it preserves this direction. each vector is on 300 dimensions.

How to do this calculation in Python.

[image]

Comment: take the cross product

Comment: As @shimo said, you need to take the cross product of the vectors. In Python you can do so by using `numpy.cross` function as shown [here](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html).

Comment: so the cross product of 2 vectors, i understand, but how about the other 2 that forms the plane together. sorry, am linear algebra newbie, how many times i need to do cross product?

Comment: I think more clarification is needed as what's the use case that you intersect 4 lines to form a plane? Because, if it's related to linear algebra, you can form a plane only using two lines. If your use case is more like linear programming where you form a convex feasible region from your constraints (each a line in a 2D space), then that's something else.